# Name for a set which has an order?

Tags: set-theory, terminology

As we all know, a *set* is a collection of elements which have no particular order and no multiplicity.

So what do you call a construct which *does* store its elements in a specific order? What is the correct mathematical term for that?

(I looked at "ordered set", but that apparently means something quite different - it is a set who's elements support order comparisons.)

Comment: [Sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence)?

Comment: And if @J.D.'s guess is wrong, you'll have to tell us what, precisely, you mean by the phrase “store its elements in a specific order”.

Comment: Looks like that's the right answer. But I can't accept comments, only answers. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Wikipedia entry on sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence):

> In mathematics, a sequence is an ordered list of objects (or events). Like a set, it contains members (also called elements, or terms), and the number of ordered element (possibly infinite) is called the length of the sequence. Unlike a set, order matters, and exactly the same elements can appear multiple times at different positions in the sequence.

Comment: I thought "sequence" meant the same as "series". But apparently it does not...

Comment: It's common confusion. [Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)#Definition) is the associated sum of a sequence.

Comment: Yes, I see that now.

Comment: Since this is MATH.stackexchange: a sequence is a surjective map $I\rightarrow X$, where $I$ is a totally(?) ordered set. The elements of $X$ are the members of the sequence. So a sequence is a particular case of an indexed set.

Comment: @Hagen: So the identity on $\mathbb R$ is also a sequence? After all, it is a surjective map $I\to X$ (where both $I$ and $X$ are $\mathbb R$), and $I$ (that is, $\mathbb R$) is totally ordered.

Comment: Yes, why not. If you do not insist on countability ...